# Javascript Regex - grab delimiter from price

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider these four different prices:

3 900,38 zł

1.900,00 €

$100,000.00

NOK 9 853,05

I want to grab all delimiters from these strings. Depending on the language, delimiters could be either a comma, a period, or a space (see polish). Basically I need to match one of these [\s,\.] when it occurs between two digits (I don't want to match white space that appears as a part of the currency symbol formatting).

Here is my regex:

```
/(?:\d([\s,\.])\d)/g
```

The problem is that the match always includes the digits on either side of the delimiter. Is there a way to return the matches WITHOUT the digits? I'm confused as to why the digits are returning in the first place since they're in a non-capturing group.

**NOTE: I already have alternate solutions but this question really is asking if this is possible to accomplish with one regex and despite javascript's lack of a look behind. Thanks!***

Here is my code pen:
http://codepen.io/nhmaggiej/pen/LEabZY

Thanks!

Comment: that actually doesn't work for Norwegian Krone, sorry, should have added that example: https://regex101.com/r/dG5fH8/1

Comment: In absence of lookbehind in JS you will have to use `\d([\s,.])(?=\d)` regex [as in this demo and grab capture group #1](https://regex101.com/r/dG5fH8/2)

Comment: You want to grab the delimiters and then...do what with them?

Comment: I am trying to identify for a given language what the delimiters are. So the last capture returned will be identified as the decimal delimiter. The other captures are the thousands separator. I need to determine this because I'm stripping the prices down to an integer, adding the prices up, and then restoring the proper formatting. The delimiters must match the language conventions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it works (for the first match only?) with `RegExp.exec(string)`:

```
var delimiterRegex = new RegExp(/\d(,)\d/g);
console.log(delimiterRegex.exec('3 900,38 zł'))
```

It seems that `String.match()` does not return the captured groups, but all the matches in the string.

There's details in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Answer (score 0):

The “match” method ignores brackets with “g”-option, use multiple “exec” instead:

```
var numbers = ["3 900,38 zł", "1.900,00 €", "$100,000.00"],
    regexp  = /\d([\s\,\.])\d/g,
    results = [], temp = []

for (var i=0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    var numberOfIccurences = (numbers[i].match(regexp) || []).length
    temp = []
    for (var j = 0; j < numberOfIccurences; j++ ) {
        temp.push( regexp.exec( numbers[i] )[1] )
    }
    results.push( temp )
}
console.log( results )
```

Here you can play with it: https://jsfiddle.net/sdLj5qay/